# Currenttime and duration with soundcloud in javascript

Tags: javascript, data-binding, soundcloud

Well, I try to put on my right next to bar top right time sound playback streamed. I looked everywhere, there are many methods for audio ogg to mp3 etc. but nothing simple to show the time of his soundcloud.
An idea ?

here is my code:

```html
<head>

  <!-- SoundCloud-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js"></script>
  <script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk-2.0.0.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>




<body>


  <div id="slider-volume"></div>

  <script src='//w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js'></script>

  <div class="player">
    <span class='info'></span>
    <div class="waveform"></div>
    <div class="position"></div>
    <div id="playSound"></div>
    <div id="stopSound"></div>
  </div>

  <iframe class="sc-widget" src="//w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=//soundcloud.com/cob/catchme&amp;color=FF9900&amp;show_bpm=true&amp;hide_related=true&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=true"></iframe>


</body>



<style type="text/css">
  body {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent;
  }
  #slider-volume {
    position: absolute;
    top: 29px;
    left: 75px;
    height: 5px;
    background: rgba(255, 86, 0, 1);
    border-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 190px;
    border: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #slider-volume .ui-slider-range-min {
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-width: 0px;
    background: rgba(255, 153, 0, 1);
    border: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #slider-volume .ui-slider-handle {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    top: -2.5px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(251, 27, 10, 1);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #slider-volume .ui-slider-handle:hover,
  #slider-volume:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }
  #playSound {
    z-index: 5;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(251, 27, 10, 1);
    border: 1px solid rgba(251, 27, 10, 1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 7px;
    left: 37px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url(${resourcesFolderName}/play_hover_c.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #stopSound {
    z-index: 5;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(251, 27, 10, 1);
    border: 1px solid rgba(251, 27, 10, 1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 7px;
    left: 7px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url(${resourcesFolderName}/pause_hover_c.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #playSound:hover {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px solid white inset;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 7px;
    left: 37px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url(${resourcesFolderName}/play_c.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    border-color: transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.2);
  }
  #stopSound:hover {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px solid white inset;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 7px;
    left: 7px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url(${resourcesFolderName}/pause_c.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    border-color: transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.2);
  }
  iframe {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 166px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 86, 0, 1);
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }
  .player {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    top: 4px;
    left: 75px;
    /*4 et 75*/
    margin: auto;
    height: 20px;
    width: 190px;
    font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(251, 27, 10, 0.9);
    transition: background-image 1s linear;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }
  .waveform {
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 86, 10, 0.1);
    transition: background-image 1s linear;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }
  .position {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(251, 153, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: width .1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }
  .info {
    user-select: none;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    left: 70px;
    margin: 0.3em -5.5em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    letter-spacing: .03em;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
  }
  .player .waveform:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }
</style>



<script type="text/javascript">
  SC.initialize({
    client_id: "70919eb43a47839a9c5fe09ae9be450f",
    redirect_uri: "http://127.0.0.1:64184/preview/callback",
  });

  var sounds = null;


  SC.stream("/tracks/225335752", {
    autoPlay: false,
    show_comments: true,
    show_user: true,
  }, function(sound) {
    var widget1 = SC.Widget($('iframe.sc-widget')[0]);

    $("#slider-volume").slider("option", "step", 0.01);
    $("#slider-volume").slider("option", "max", 1);
    $("#slider-volume").slider("option", "value", sound.getVolume());



    $('#playSound').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      widget1.toggle();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });


    $('#stopSound').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      widget1.pause();
      e.stopPropagation();
      widget1.seekTo(0);

    });


    $("#slider-volume").on("slidechange", function(event, ui) {
      widget1.setVolume(ui.value);
    });


  });


  $(function() {
    $("#slider-volume").slider();
  });

  $("#slider-volume").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    value: 100,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val(ui.value);
    }
  });



  $(document).ready(function() {

    var player = SC.Widget($('iframe.sc-widget')[0]);
    var pOffset = $('.player').offset();
    var pWidth = $('.player').width();
    var scrub;

    player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
      setInfo();
      player.pause();
    }); //Set info on load

    player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY_PROGRESS, function(e) {
      if (e.relativePosition < 0.003) {
        setInfo();
      }
      //Event listener when track is playing
      $('.position').css('width', (e.relativePosition * 100) + "%");
    });

    $('.player').mousemove(function(e) { //Get position of mouse for scrubbing
      scrub = (e.pageX - pOffset.left);
    });

    $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 32:
          player.toggle();
          break;
        case 39:
          player.next();
          break;
        case 37:
          player.prev();
          break;
      }
    });

    $('.player').click(function() { //Use the position to seek when clicked
      $('.position').css('width', scrub + "px");
      var seek = player.duration * (scrub / pWidth);

      //Seeking to the start would be a previous?
      if (seek < player.duration * 0.05) {
        player.prev();
      } else if (seek > player.duration * 0.99) {
        player.next();
      } else {
        player.seekTo(seek);
      }

    });

    function setInfo() {
      player.getCurrentSound(function(song) {
        console.log(song);

        $('.position').css('background-color');
        $('.player').css('background-color');

        var info = song.title;
        $('.info').html(info);

        player.current = song;
      });

      player.getDuration(function(value) {
        player.duration = value;
      });

      player.isPaused(function(bool) {
        player.getPaused = bool;
      });


    }

  });
</script>
```

I'm not very good code, it is not my profession, but I'm learning every day new features.

What I would do is :

- trigger the play button of the iframe soundcloud: ok done
- stop it: ok done
- volume works with the current sound: ok done
- but display the currentTime and duration and that works with the current playback: ???

I tried this with an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ldc2N/

but I would like the time is displayed in real time.

Any info would help me

best

Answer (score 1):

The following code will set the contents of a html element to 'duration' every second:

```
            //repeat every interval (1s)
            setInterval(function(){ 
                widget.getDuration(function(duration){
                        //Set inner html of element with id duration to duration
                        $('#duration').html(duration); 
                    });
               }
            ,1000); //Interval in ms
```

Comment: @cob If I understand you right, you are trying to synchronize data that exists in your javascript with elements in your view. To do this you have to watch for changes to values in javascript and apply these to the view. This is called 'Data-Binding'. The easiest way to do this is to use a framework or library that does this for you. I'd advice you to look into lightweight Data-Binding libraries (Rivet.JS advertises itself as such, although I have no experience with it).

Answer (score 0):

Great for HARTGER answer.

I tried for another solution. Your solution is best, but now I put, what I understand ... , automatic currentTime and duration in the html , I do not know if I did well ???

Now I try to put the number of read ( play_count ) apart ... I look around a simple way to integrate it.

But in any case , thank you for your answer.

best

-cob-

```html
<head>

  <!-- SoundCloud-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js"></script>
  <script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk-2.0.0.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</head>




<body>


  <div id="slider-volume">
    <input type="text" id="amount" readonly>
  </div>



  <script src='//w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js'></script>

  <div class="player">
    <span class='info'></span>
    <div class="waveform"></div>
    <div class="position"></div>
    <div id="playSound"></div>
    <div id="stopSound"></div>
    <div class="timer" id="playerTime">00:00</div>
    <div class="duration">- 04:15</div>
  </div>

  <iframe class="sc-widget" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="//w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=//soundcloud.com/cob/catchme&amp;color=FF9900&amp;show_bpm=true&amp;hide_related=true&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=true"></iframe>




</body>



<style type="text/css">
  body {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
  }
  #slider-volume {
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;
    top: 29px;
    left: 75px;
    height: 5px;
    background: rgba(255, 86, 0, 1);
    border-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 190px;
    border: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    cursor: default;
  }
  #slider-volume .ui-slider-range-min {
    z-index: 6;
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-width: 0px;
    background: rgba(255, 153, 0, 1);
    border: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    cursor: default;
  }
  #slider-volume .ui-slider-handle {
    z-index: 7;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    top: -2.5px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background: rgba(251, 27, 10, 1);
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }
  #slider-volume .ui-slider-handle:hover,
  #slider-volume:hover {
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }
  #amount {
    top: 10px;
    left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 45px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/72fq2mbo90d2if4/tips-volume.png) no-repeat scroll 0% 50%;
    background-size: 110%;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    text-align: right;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  #amount:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  #playSound {
    z-index: 5;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(251, 27, 10, 1);
    border: 1px solid rgba(251, 27, 10, 1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 7px;
    left: 37px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url(${resourcesFolderName}/play_hover_c.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    cursor: default;
  }
  #stopSound {
    z-index: 5;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(251, 27, 10, 1);
    border: 1px solid rgba(251, 27, 10, 1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 7px;
    left: 7px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url(${resourcesFolderName}/pause_hover_c.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    cursor: default;
  }
  #playSound:hover {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px solid white inset;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 7px;
    left: 37px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url(${resourcesFolderName}/play_c.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    border-color: transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.2);
  }
  #stopSound:hover {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px solid white inset;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 7px;
    left: 7px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url(${resourcesFolderName}/pause_c.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    border-color: transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.2);
  }
  iframe {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 130px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 86, 0, 1);
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }
  .player {
    cursor: default;
    position: fixed;
    top: 4px;
    left: 75px;
    /*4 et 75*/
    margin: auto;
    height: 20px;
    width: 190px;
    background-color: rgba(251, 27, 10, 0.9);
    transition: background-image 1s linear;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }
  .waveform {
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 86, 10, 0.1);
    transition: background-image 1s linear;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }
  .position {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(251, 153, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: width .1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }
  .info {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    left: 70px;
    margin: 0.3em -5.5em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    letter-spacing: .03em;
    font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
  }
  .player .waveform:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }
  .timer {
    position: absolute;
  }
  #playerTime {
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin: 0px 0 0 0px;
    top: 3px;
    right: 45px;
    color: white;
  }
  .duration {
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 10px;
    color: white;
  }
</style>



<script type="text/javascript">
  String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function() {
    var sec_num = parseInt(this, 10);
    var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60) - 1;
    if (hours < 10) {
      hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
      minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
      seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    var time = '' + minutes + ':' + seconds; // si heure hours+':'
    return time;
  }

  SC.initialize({
    client_id: "70919eb43a47839a9c5fe09ae9be450f",
    redirect_uri: "http://127.0.0.1:64184/preview/callback",
  });

  var sounds = null;


  SC.stream("/tracks/225335752", {
    autoPlay: false,
    show_comments: true,
    show_user: true,
  }, function(sound) {
    var widget1 = SC.Widget($('iframe.sc-widget')[0]);

    $("#slider-volume").slider("option", "step", 0.01);
    $("#slider-volume").slider("option", "max", 1);
    $("#slider-volume").slider("option", "value", sound.getVolume());



    $('#playSound').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      widget1.toggle();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });


    $('#stopSound').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      widget1.pause();
      e.stopPropagation();
      widget1.seekTo(0);

    });


    $("#slider-volume").on("slidechange", function(event, ui) {
      widget1.setVolume(ui.value);
    });


  });


  $(function() {

    $("#slider-volume").slider({
      orientation: "horizontal",
      range: "min",
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      value: 100,


      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val((ui.value * 100).toFixed() + ' %');
      },
      create: function(event, ui) {
        $(event.target).find('.ui-slider-handle').append(amount);
      },

    });

    $("#amount").val($("#slider-volume").slider("value").toFixed() + ' %');




  });



  $(document).ready(function() {

    var player = SC.Widget($('iframe.sc-widget')[0]);
    var pOffset = $('.player').offset();
    var pWidth = $('.player').width();
    var scrub;


    player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
      setInfo();
      player.pause();
    }); //Set info on load

    player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY_PROGRESS, function(progress) {
      var seconds = Math.ceil(progress.currentPosition / 1000);
      var secondsF = String(seconds).toHHMMSS();
      $('#playerTime').html(secondsF);
    });


    player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY_PROGRESS, function(e) {
      if (e.relativePosition < 0.003) {
        setInfo();
      }
      //Event listener when track is playing
      $('.position').css('width', (e.relativePosition * 100) + "%");
    });

    $('.player').mousemove(function(e) { //Get position of mouse for scrubbing
      scrub = (e.pageX - pOffset.left);
    });

    $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 32:
          player.toggle();
          break;
        case 39:
          player.next();
          break;
        case 37:
          player.prev();
          break;
      }
    });

    $('.player').click(function() { //Use the position to seek when clicked
      $('.position').css('width', scrub + "px");
      var seek = player.duration * (scrub / pWidth);

      //Seeking to the start would be a previous?
      if (seek < player.duration * 0.05) {
        player.prev();
      } else if (seek > player.duration * 0.99) {
        player.next();
      } else {
        player.seekTo(seek);
      }

    });

    function setInfo() {
      player.getCurrentSound(function(song) {
        console.log(song);

        $('.position').css('background-color');
        $('.player').css('background-color');

        var info = song.title;
        $('.info').html(info);

        player.current = song;
      });

      player.getDuration(function(value) {
        player.duration = value;
      });

      player.isPaused(function(bool) {
        player.getPaused = bool;
      });


    }

  });
</script>
```